# SharePoint 2013 iFrame vs app

Tags: sharepoint-2013

What is the difference between 1) an ASP.NET application exposed in SharePoint by an IFrame 
and
2) a SharePoint 2013 App exposed through an app part.

Say both use CSOM and resides in intranet on a separate server (SharePoint App is provider hosted on a server in intranet ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use iframe you have to face few issues:

- No current SharePoint Context
- No Out of the box SharePoint Security
- It is harder to maintain

App approach (this approach is recommended by M$):

- SharePoint Context available
- SharePoint security available out of the box
- App Part can be easily maintained (added, removed)

Comment: What is the difference between sharepoint context and client context? IMO both Iframe-web-application and sharepoint-app has access to clientcontext for CSOM/Rest-API.

Comment: It is the same. In external application you cannot get current SPClientContext because there is none. Of course you can create one if you want.

Comment: Since we can create it, can't we take 'No SharePoint Context' out from the difference? Just to confirm

Comment: You forgot the most important thing about asp.net exposed through iframe - if this web application is located in another domain you won't be able to display it in iframe in sharepoint because it is considered as cross site scripting attack(browser blocks it).

Comment: That is why when you create autohosted app (which is basically separate web application provided as link in sharepoint UI) it is not displayed in SharePoint it self in iframe and only link provided in UI.